# Find distance from a node to the one farthest from it BOOST

Tags: c++, boost, c++11, nodes, longest-path

I need to fin the distance from all nodes to the node farthest from it in the minimum spanning tree. I have done this so far but I got no clue as to find the longest distance from a node.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<boost/config.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/adjacency_list.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/kruskal_min_spanning_tree.hpp>
#include<boost/graph/prim_minimum_spanning_tree.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;

int main()
{
typedef adjacency_list< vecS, vecS, undirectedS, property <vertex_distance_t,int>, property< edge_weight_t, int> > Graph;
int test=0,m,a,b,c,w,d,i,no_v,no_e,arr_w[100],arr_d[100];
cin>>test;
m=0;
while(m!=test)
{
cin>>no_v>>no_e;
Graph g(no_v);
property_map <Graph, edge_weight_t>:: type weightMap=get(edge_weight,g);
bool bol;
graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor ed;

for(i=0;i<no_e;i++)
{
cin>>a>>b>>c;
tie(ed,bol)=add_edge(a,b,g);
weightMap[ed]=c;
}

property_map<Graph,edge_weight_t>::type weightM=get(edge_weight,g);
property_map<Graph,vertex_distance_t>::type distanceMap=get(vertex_distance,g);
property_map<Graph,vertex_index_t>::type indexMap=get(vertex_index,g);

vector< graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor> spanning_tree;

kruskal_minimum_spanning_tree(g,back_inserter(spanning_tree));

vector<graph_traits<Graph>::vector_descriptor>p(no_v);

prim_minimum_spanning_tree(g,0,&p[0],distancemap,weightMap,indexMap,default_dijkstra_visitor());



w=0;

for(vector<graph_traits<Graph>::edge_descriptor>::iterator eb=spanning_tree.begin();eb!=spanning_tree.end();++eb) //spanning tree weight
{
w=w+weightM[*eb];
}

arr_w[m]=w;
d=0;

graph_traits<Graph>::vertex_iterator vb,ve;

for(tie(vb,ve)=vertices(g),.

arr_d[m]=d;
m++;
}

for( i=0;i<test;i++)
{
cout<<arr_w[i]<<endl;
}

return 0;
}
```

If i have a spanning tree with nodes 1 2 3 4 I need to find longest distance from 1 2 3 4 in the spanning tree(and the longest distance can comprise of many edges not only one).

Comment: What about time complexity. Is O(n^2) good enough? Because naive solution is this good.

Comment: I havnt been able to come up with anything.so i think for starters naive solution would be good,even tough ive been trying to figure out a smarter one.

Answer (score 0):

I'll not give you exact code how to do this but I'll give you and idea how to do this.

First, result of MST (minimum spanning tree) is so called tree. Think about the definition. One can say it is a graph where exists path from every node to every other nodes and there are no cycles. Alternatively you can say that given graph is a tree iff exists exactly one path from vertex u to v for every u and v.

According to the definition you can define following

```
function DFS_Farthest (Vertex u, Vertices P)
begin
    define farthest is 0
    define P0 as empty set
    add u to P

    foreach v from neighbours of u and v is not in P do
    begin
        ( len, Ps ) = DFS_Farthest(v, P)
        if L(u, v) + len > farthest then
        begin
            P0 is Ps union P
            farthest is len + L(u, v)
        end
    end

    return (farthest, P0)
end
```

Then you'll for every vertex v in graph call `DFS_Farthest(v, empty set)` and it'll give you (farthest, P) where farthest is distance of the farthest node and P is set of vertices from which you can reconstruct the path from v to farthest vertex.

So now to describe what is it doing. First the signature. First parameter is from what vertex you want to know farthest one. Second parameter is a set of banned vertices. So it says "Hey, give me the longest path from v to farthest vertex so the vertices from P are not in that path".

Next there is this `foreach` thing. There you are looking for farthest vertices from current vertex without visiting vertices already in P (current vertex is already there). When you find path longer then currently found not it to `farthest` and `P0`. Note that `L(u, v)` is length of the edge {u, v}.

At the end you'll return those length and banned vertices (this is the path to the farthest vertex).

This is just simple DFS (depth first search) algorithm where you remember already visited vertices.

Now about time complexity. Suppose you can get neighbours of given vertex in O(1) (depends on data structure you have). Function visits every vertex exactly once. So it is at least O(N). To know farthest vertex from every vertex you have to call this function for every vertex. This gives you time complexity of this solution of your's problem at least O(n^2).

My guess is that better solution might be done using dynamic programming but this is just a guess. Generally finding longest path in graph is NP-hard problem. This makes me suspicious that there might not me any significantly better solution. But it's another guess.